# Entity framework: Properties with '1' suffix

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following schema in my Code First project:

```
public class MyModel {
    public ModelType MType {get;set;}
    public string PropA {get;set;}
    public string PropB {get;set;}
    public string PropC {get;set;}
}

public class MyFirstObj : MyModel
{
    public ModelType MType {get;set;} = 1
    [Required]
    public string PropC {get;set;}
}

public class MyOtherObj : MyModel, IHasPropAB
{
    public ModelType MType {get;set;} = 2
    [Required]
    public string PropA {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string PropB {get;set;}

    public string PropC {get { return "[${PropA} {PropB}]"}}
}
```

this works as expected, I have all 3 fields (PropA, PropB, PropC) in the database. But if I add a new definition:

```
public class MyOtherObj2 : MyModel, IHasPropAB
{
    public ModelType MType {get;set;} = 3
    [Required]
    public string PropA {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string PropB { get; set;}

    public string PropC {get { return "[${PropA} {PropB}]"}}
}
```

the EF generator sets up new fields in the DB, it creates PropA1 and PropB1 next to PropA and PropB. Why the difference? How can I map all fields correctly?

Comment: Firstly, this code won't compile. Are they all classes? You appear to be hiding members here in the derived classes - don't do that.

Comment: @DavidG thanks, see edited. Why not to hide members?

Comment: Because it's confusing and now your class kinda has two properties with the same name, that's what is confusing Entity Framework. Instead you can configure the derived models using the fluent API if you need to make the properties `Required` or perhaps using the `new` keyword but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Hiding members violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) of object oriented design.